# Windows 7 Login like WindowsXP

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, login

I do not like Windows 7's default method of user login. I don't want my users to have to click on their icon & then enter their password. I believe this is a security flaw since it tells anyone what accounts exist on the computer. I'd much rather use the same login method used in Windows XP, where the user types in their userID & password.
Can anyone tell me how to accomplish this task?

Comment: xp famously had the method of displaying login names with icons, that was default but xp had the traditional method too

Answer (score 3):

1. Click Start, type `gpedit.msc`, and then press Enter. This opens the Local Group Policy Editor with the top-level Local Group Policy object open for editing.
2. In the editor, expand Local Computer Policy, Computer Configuration, Administrative Templates, System, Logon.
3. Double-click *Always Use Classic Logon*.
4. Select *Enabled*, and then click *OK*.

[Source](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ff394947.aspx)